# How can I get matching records that are multiple relationships apart with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have four tables/classes: `Group`. `Bank`, `Question`, and `Survey`. Surveys have many questions, questions belong to a bank which in turn belong to a group. I have the group and the survey (I'm in an instance method of `Survey` and am looping through all the `Group` instances), and want to know which questions belong to both.

```python
class Group(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    banks = db.relationship('Bank', backref='group')


class Bank(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    group_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('group.id')
    questions = db.relationship('Question', backref='bank', lazy='dynamic')


class Question(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    survey_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('survey.id')
    bank_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('bank.id')


class Survey(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    questions = db.relationship('Question', backref='survey', lazy='dynamic')
```

I thought of trying something like `self.questions.filter(Question.bank.in_(group.banks))` (`self` being a `Survey` instance), but got a `NotImplementedError`. Right now I'm using ugly nested `for` loops with `if` conditions, and am trying to clean it up, especially since I anticipate there being a speed issue as the number of surveys and questions increase.

```python
for group in groups:
    for bank in group.banks:
      for question in bank.questions:
          if question in self.questions:
              # do stuff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [joins](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html#querying-with-joins) to traverse the relationship get the information that you want.

This query joins the survey table to the bank table on their shared foreign question id key, then joins the bank table to the group table.

```
q = (session.query(Survey.id, Question.id, Group.id)
            .join(Survey.questions, Bank)
            .join(Group)
            .filter(Survey.id == self.id)
            .all())
```

To get information for all surveys in one query, remove the `filter` clause.

The SQL generated by the query is

```sql
SELECT survey.id AS survey_id, question.id AS question_id, "group".id AS group_id                                                                                                                
    FROM survey 
        JOIN question ON survey.id = question.survey_id 
        JOIN bank ON bank.id = question.bank_id 
        JOIN "group" ON "group".id = bank.group_id                                                                                                                          
    WHERE survey.id = ?
```

Comment: I really need to study joins more. What I ended up doing was getting all of the bank ids for the group, and then filtering the survey's questions based on them having a bank id in that set: `self.questions.filter(Question.bank_id.in_([bank.id for bank in group.banks]))`. It's probably less direct than your method, but until I understand what yours does, I'll use it.